# List of scalar values from entity framework query

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

Let say I have Customers table in a database. I'd like to create List of CustomerNames using entity framework 4.1. How can I do that in Visual Basic?

```
Dim customerNames = (From c In _context.Customers
                     Select New With {c.CustomerName}).ToList()
```

brings a list of anonymous objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a `List<String>` with the customer names, then select the `CustomerName` without creating anonymous objects:

```
Dim customerNames = (From c In Users
                     Select c.UserName).ToList()
```